# Java, drag and drop to change the order of panels

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

Ok so what I have set up is as follows. I have a java 1.7 project that uses javax.swing for the ui. This is my first project outside of following tutorials, it is a initiative tracker for those that are familiar with table top. I have a class that extends JPanel (and implements Comparable<>) so I can add it dynamically and story different data for each class.

The panels are added to the layout, with its y position depending on how many panels are already there. They are also added to an ArrayList to sort them in order.
The list can be sorted by one of the properties of the class.

What I am now running into is that I want to manually be able to drag and drop them to change the order, both in layout and in the ArrayList. With an added note that I can't just remove and re-add one because I would lose the values saved in the class.

Toward this end I made a JButton that needs to do the following:

- So long as the mouse is pressed down on the button, the panel it belongs to needs to be dragged with the mouse.
- When the mouse is released it needs to check its position and if necessary go to that spot.

[So for example](http://i36.photobucket.com/albums/e9/ejkrielen/ex_zpsfafc2fe1.png)

I have tried some drop and drag tutorials but I can't seem to find one that I can adjust into what I want.

Edit1: This is what I tried.

```
MouseListener listener = new DragMouseAdapter();
dragButton.addMouseListener(listener);
dragButton.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text"));
```

And then

```
class DragMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();
        TransferHandler handler = c.getTransferHandler();
        handler.exportAsDrag(c, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
        // TODO make it a swap location drag and drop
    }
}
```

This was from a tutorial and it succesfully changes the text and all but that is not at all what I want and I don't know how to change it up to do what I want.

Edit2: [This tutorial](http://bryanesmith.com/docs/drag-and-drop-java-5/) describes what I want to do, except it doesn't work. It gives the following error:

```
    Step 1 of 7: Mouse pressed. Going to export our RandomDragAndDropPanel so that it is draggable.
Step 2 of 7: Returning the acceptable TransferHandler action. Our RandomDragAndDropPanel accepts Copy only.
Step 3 of 7: Casting the RandomDragAndDropPanel as Transferable. The Transferable RandomDragAndDropPanel will be queried for acceptable DataFlavors as it enters drop targets, as well as eventually present the target with the Object it transfers.
Step 4 of 7: Querying for acceptable DataFlavors to determine what is available. Our example only supports our custom RandomDragAndDropPanel DataFlavor.
Problem lazy loading: RandomDragAndDropPanel
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RandomDragAndDropPanel
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor.tryToLoadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at DnD.DragAndDropPanelsDemo.getDragAndDropPanelDataFlavor(DragAndDropPanelsDemo.java:197)
    at DnD.RandomDragAndDropPanel.getTransferDataFlavors(DragAndDropPanelsDemo.java:392)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.getFormatsForTransferable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDragSourceContextPeer.startDrag(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.startDrag(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.startDrag(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent.startDrag(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$DragHandler.dragGestureRecognized(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragGestureRecognizer.fireDragGestureRecognized(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$SwingDragGestureRecognizer.gestured(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler.exportAsDrag(Unknown Source)
    at DnD.DraggableMouseListener.mousePressed(DragAndDropPanelsDemo.java:456)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please, could you post your attempts so that we can help you find out what's wrong?

Comment: I will edit that in, but the problem mostly is not that my code isn't working but I don't know what the code should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of drag and drop to change the order of panels(does not support sorting).

[image]

1. `DragMouseAdapter#mouseDragged(...)`: search drag panel, remove form parent panel and open cursor window.
2. `DragMouseAdapter#mouseReleased(...)`: search drop location, insert dragging panel, close cursor window.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.dnd.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RearrangeOrderOfPanelsTest2 {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    DragMouseAdapter dh = new DragMouseAdapter();
    box.addMouseListener(dh);
    box.addMouseMotionListener(dh);

    int idx = 0;
    for (JComponent c : Arrays.asList(
           new JLabel("<html>111<br>11<br>11"),
           new JButton("2"), new JCheckBox("3"), new JTextField(14))) {
      box.add(createToolbarButton(idx++, c));
    }
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    return p;
  }

  private static JComponent createToolbarButton(int i, JComponent c) {
    JLabel l = new JLabel(String.format(" %04d ", i));
    l.setOpaque(true);
    l.setBackground(Color.RED);
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                  BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5),
                  BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2)));
    p.add(l, BorderLayout.WEST);
    p.add(c);
    p.setOpaque(false);
    return p;
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }

  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new RearrangeOrderOfPanelsTest2().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class DragMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
  private static final int xoffset = 16;
  private static final Rectangle R1 = new Rectangle();
  private static final Rectangle R2 = new Rectangle();
  private static Rectangle prevRect;
  private final JWindow window = new JWindow();
  private Component draggingComonent;
  private int index = -1;
  private Component gap;
  private Point startPt;
  private Point dragOffset;
  private final int gestureMotionThreshold = DragSource.getDragThreshold();

  public DragMouseAdapter() {
    super();
    window.setBackground(new Color(0, true));
  }

  @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    JComponent parent = (JComponent) e.getComponent();
    if (parent.getComponentCount() <= 1) {
      startPt = null;
      return;
    }
    startPt = e.getPoint();
  }

  private void startDragging(JComponent parent, Point pt) {
    //get a dragging panel
    Component c = parent.getComponentAt(pt);
    index = parent.getComponentZOrder(c);
    if (Objects.equals(c, parent) || index < 0) {
      return;
    }
    draggingComonent = c;
    Dimension d = draggingComonent.getSize();

    Point dp = draggingComonent.getLocation();
    dragOffset = new Point(pt.x - dp.x, pt.y - dp.y);

    //make a dummy filler
    gap = Box.createRigidArea(d);
    swapComponentLocation(parent, c, gap, index);

    //make a cursor window
    window.add(draggingComonent);
    window.pack();

    updateWindowLocation(pt, parent);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }

  private void updateWindowLocation(Point pt, JComponent parent) {
    Point p = new Point(pt.x - dragOffset.x, pt.y - dragOffset.y);
    SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, parent);
    window.setLocation(p);
  }

  private static int getTargetIndex(Rectangle r, Point pt, int i) {
    int ht2 = (int)(.5 + r.height * .5);
    R1.setBounds(r.x, r.y,       r.width, ht2);
    R2.setBounds(r.x, r.y + ht2, r.width, ht2);
    if (R1.contains(pt)) {
      prevRect = R1;
      return i - 1 > 0 ? i : 0;
    } else if (R2.contains(pt)) {
      prevRect = R2;
      return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }
  private static void swapComponentLocation(
      Container parent, Component remove, Component add, int idx) {
    parent.remove(remove);
    parent.add(add, idx);
    parent.revalidate();
    parent.repaint();
  }

  @Override public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    Point pt = e.getPoint();
    JComponent parent = (JComponent) e.getComponent();

    //MotionThreshold
    double a = Math.pow(pt.x - startPt.x, 2);
    double b = Math.pow(pt.y - startPt.y, 2);
    if (draggingComonent == null &&
        Math.sqrt(a + b) > gestureMotionThreshold) {
      startDragging(parent, pt);
      return;
    }
    if (!window.isVisible() || draggingComonent == null) {
      return;
    }

    //update the cursor window location
    updateWindowLocation(pt, parent);
    if (prevRect != null && prevRect.contains(pt)) {
      return;
    }

    //change the dummy filler location
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getComponentCount(); i++) {
      Component c = parent.getComponent(i);
      Rectangle r = c.getBounds();
      if (Objects.equals(c, gap) && r.contains(pt)) {
        return;
      }
      int tgt = getTargetIndex(r, pt, i);
      if (tgt >= 0) {
        swapComponentLocation(parent, gap, gap, tgt);
        return;
      }
    }
    parent.remove(gap);
    parent.revalidate();
  }

  @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    startPt = null;
    if (!window.isVisible() || draggingComonent == null) {
      return;
    }
    Point pt = e.getPoint();
    JComponent parent = (JComponent) e.getComponent();

    //close the cursor window
    Component cmp = draggingComonent;
    draggingComonent = null;
    prevRect = null;
    startPt = null;
    dragOffset = null;
    window.setVisible(false);

    //swap the dragging panel and the dummy filler
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getComponentCount(); i++) {
      Component c = parent.getComponent(i);
      if (Objects.equals(c, gap)) {
        swapComponentLocation(parent, gap, cmp, i);
        return;
      }
      int tgt = getTargetIndex(c.getBounds(), pt, i);
      if (tgt >= 0) {
        swapComponentLocation(parent, gap, cmp, tgt);
        return;
      }
    }
    if (parent.getParent().getBounds().contains(pt)) {
      swapComponentLocation(parent, gap, cmp, parent.getComponentCount());
    } else {
      swapComponentLocation(parent, gap, cmp, index);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed what I want, that it doesn't support sorting isn't a big deal I can probably add that in myself later. But what is an issue is that I don't understand which part of the code does what, it has almost no explanation of what does what or why certain things were used. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Add some comments to the source code to explain `DragMouseAdapter`.